# how to best deal with a bunch of references in a class

Tags: c++

I have a class that references a bunch of other classes.  I want to be able to add these references incrementally (i.e. not all at the same time on the constructor), and I want to disallow the ability to delete the object underlying these references from my class, also I want to test for NULL-ness on these references so I know a particular reference has not been added.  What is a good design to accomplish these requirements?

Comment: You seem to be describing pointers. Consider boost::shared_ptr (and other smart pointer types). Not sure what you mean by "disallow the ability to delete the object", though. If you have a reference, the compiler can't stop you typing "delete &blah;".

Comment: Indeed. Why not use pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with other comments that you should use `boost::shared_ptr`.

However if you don't want the class holding these references to part-control the lifetime of the objects it references you should consider using `boost::weak_ptr` to hold the references then turn this into a `shared_ptr` when you want to us it.  This will allow the referenced objects to be deleted before your class, and you will always know if object has been deleted before using it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be trying to build a [Service Locator](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/ServiceLocator.html).

As a side-comment: I would personally recommend not doing that, because [it is going to make testing really, really painful if you ever want to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0).  Constructor injection (Something that you are trying to avoid) will make testing much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use the refcounted class, so that your reference will be managed until your primary class get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all the recommendations that you use boost:;shared_pointer, it is far from obvious from your post that it would be appropriate to do so, as the class appears to have no ownership semantics. An ordinary C++ pointer will do just fine here.

It is difficult at the end of the day to prevent deletion via  smart pointer, as the 
smart pointer must, in some form or other, provide access to the underlying dumb pointer, which of course can always be deleted. For some problems there is no technological solution, and in this case a code review is the best way to detect semantic errors in using the contained pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The object you want to reference could be derived from with something like this. That would prevent you from deleting them.

class T
class NonDeletable : public T
{ 
private: 
void operator delete(void*); 
};